# Internal Server Error in nginx when uploading bigger files greater than 15MB

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using parallel plesk 11 , and there is service of nginx as reverse proxy server and i am using that , Whenever i try to upload the file size greater than 15MB it gives internal server error. I am not able to find out the problem that is causing this issue. 
I am providing the php.ini settings. After checking do tell me any solution, its very urgent to know it is affecting my server services.

I am running php as fastcgi and 
settings are 
post_max_size 200M
upload_max_filesize 450M
memeory_limit 32M
safe_mode on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happened due to httpmaxrequest length error . Which was due to mod_fcgid of apache, 
so i changed the fcgid.conf present in /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf

Also this file has to be changed for proper working of uploading in parallel plesk.

MaxRequestLen in /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/domainVirtualHost.php

And After that reconfigure the domain Reconfigure domains: /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all

Restart Both nginx and apache

service nginx restart
service apache2 restart

Than everything will work fine , Uploading this way can be done. And this is major problem which happens in ubuntu 10.10 running parallel plesk 11.